# TortoiseHG Upgrade shows old version

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

We just upgraded Team City and Mecurial on our server. When I run hg --version on the server is shows version 1.8.3 instead of 2.6?

I have rebooted and in the Workbench UI it shows the correct version, just not at the command line. Any ideas?

Comment: Might simply be that tortoise hg uses the same version of hg as the last release. Note that the command line of tortoise hg is thg not hg. That is the command line of Mercurial per se.

Comment: Try `where thg` and `where hg` to see if the commands are being found in the same folder.  TortoiseHg 2.6 uses Mercurial 2.4, so you seem to have to different installations running if you are seeing 1.8.3.

Comment: Thank you both. Yes version 1.8.3 was stilled installed.

Answer (score 0):

I found that version 1.8.3 was not removed correctly and both versions were being referenced in the windows path. Since it was the first one found that is what the application was using. Manually uninstalling this corrected the issue.